# how to ungroup and mutate results to the original dataset after summing up values, R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to combine two compound commands from package "dplyr" for simplicity.

this is a hypothetical dataset

| V5 | V15 | sum | length | density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| upstream | g1 | 1234 | 17645 | 0.1 |
| upstream | g2 | 3456 | 17645 | 0.3 |
| downstream | g1 | 2345 | 17645 | 0.2 |
| downstream | g2 | 1456 | 17645 | 0.1 |

I first get the total length of each region:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(V5) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(sum(sum)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

then manually add it to a new column and extra:

```
df= df %>% mutate("region" = case_when(
    str_detect(V5, "upstream") ~ "4690",
    str_detect(V5, "downstream") ~ "3801",
))

df$Gsize <- (as.numeric(df$region)/14675549)*100
```

the function `ungroup()` doesn't do what I expected, I want the summed value be added for all variables. how can I combine the first and second functions in a way that it automatically calculates each region's size, adds it to a new column so then I can get the percentage of it? it is tedious to be done manually for many regions and many tables.

expected result:

| V5 | V15 | sum | length | density | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| upstream | g1 | 1234 | 17645 | 0.1 | 4690 |
| upstream | g2 | 3456 | 17645 | 0.3 | 4690 |
| downstream | g1 | 2345 | 17645 | 0.2 | 3801 |
| downstream | g2 | 1456 | 17645 | 0.1 | 3801 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After computing the totals, join the totals with the original dataset. Then you can proceed with your percentage calculation.

```
library(dplyr)

 df %>%
  group_by(V5) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(sum)) %>% 
  left_join(df, by = "V5")
```

Comment: thank you sir, it helped a lot. is it possible to add it as the last column instead of the second one?

Comment: Yes. You can use the dplyr relocate() function.